# ansible answers to mysql_secure_installation

Tags: bash, ansible

I can't realize how to write a task, that answers mysql_secure_installation script questions.

I only have

```
shell: mysql_secure_installation  <<< '1111' executable=/bin/bash
```

and no ideas on how to continue answering.
What would be the best way to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think you best bet is to write a playbook (or better, change your mysql role) that will reproduce `mysql_secure_installation` script. There are several reasons for this :

- the script will always return 'changed', everytime you run your playbook, which is not something you want
- writing tasks is more flexible : you can add, remove, change and adapt what you want to do according to your setup
- you can learn in the process

Basically, `mysql_secure_installation` does this :

1. sets the root password
2. removes anonymous users
3. removes root remote access
4. removes the test database

Assuming you have set up `mysql_root_password`, and added python-mysqldb like so :

```
    - name: Adds Python MySQL support on Debian/Ubuntu
      apt: pkg="python-mysqldb" state=present
      when: ansible_os_family == 'Debian'

    - name: Adds Python MySQL support on RedHat/CentOS
      yum: name=MySQL-python state=present
      when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat'
```

this can be accomplished like this :

- Setting the root password

  ```
    - name: Sets the root password 
      mysql_user: user=root password="{{ mysql_root_password }}" host=localhost
      no_log: yes
  ```
- Removing anonymous users

  ```
    - name: Deletes anonymous MySQL server user for ansible_fqdn
      mysql_user: user="" host="{{ ansible_fqdn }}" state="absent"

    - name: Deletes anonymous MySQL server user for localhost
      mysql_user: user="" state="absent"
  ```
- Removing root remote access

  ```
    - name: Secures the MySQL root user for IPV6 localhost (::1)
      mysql_user: user="root" password="{{ mysql_root_password }}" host="::1"
      no_log: yes

    - name: Secures the MySQL root user for IPV4 localhost (127.0.0.1)
      mysql_user: user="root" password="{{ mysql_root_password }}" host="127.0.0.1"
      no_log: yes 

    - name: Secures the MySQL root user for localhost domain (localhost)
      mysql_user: user="root" password="{{ mysql_root_password }}" host="localhost"
      no_log: yes 

    - name: Secures the MySQL root user for server_hostname domain
      mysql_user: user="root" password="{{ mysql_root_password }}" host="{{ ansible_fqdn }}"
      no_log: yes
  ```
- Removing the test database

  ```
    - name: Removes the MySQL test database
      mysql_db: db=test state=absent
  ```

This should do it. Note that I took a quick glance à the `mysql_secure_installation` on my system. I might have skipped something or there might be other steps included in other versions. YMMV !

Comment: Without "state=absent", wouldn't those commands to remove root remote access actually ensure that you have root remote access?

Comment: Nope. What this is doing is ensuring that root can **ONLY** connect for the local machine. Not from any other machine, i.e., remotely.

Comment: You should add no_log: yes  to all tasks so that pwds are not logged, just a heads up!

Comment: How to do this in an idempotent way? I cannot run it twice because the root password has changed

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me:

```
- name: Adds Python MySQL support on Debian/Ubuntu
  apt: pkg="python-mysqldb" state=present
  when: ansible_os_family == 'Debian'

- name: Adds Python MySQL support on RedHat/CentOS
  yum: name=MySQL-python state=present
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat'

- name: Set the root password 
  mysql_user: login_user=root login_password="{{ root_password }}" user=root password="{{ root_password }}"

- name: Secure the root user for IPV6 localhost (::1)
  mysql_user: login_user=root login_password="{{ root_password }}" user=root password="{{ root_password }}" host="::1"

- name: Secure the root user for IPV4 localhost (127.0.0.1)
  mysql_user: login_user=root login_password="{{ root_password }}" user=root password="{{ root_password }}" host="127.0.0.1"

- name: Secure the root user for localhost domain
  mysql_user: login_user=root login_password="{{ root_password }}" user=root password="{{ root_password }}" host="localhost"

- name: Secure the root user for server_hostname domain
  mysql_user: login_user=root login_password="{{ root_password }}" user=root password="{{ root_password }}" host="{{ ansible_fqdn }}"

- name: Deletes anonymous server user
  mysql_user: login_user=root login_password="{{ root_password }}" user="" host_all=yes state=absent

- name: Removes the test database
  mysql_db: login_user=root login_password="{{ root_password }}" db=test state=absent
```

Comment: For me this didn't work. I had to change the line to set the root password to:```- name: Set the root password 
  mysql_user: login_user=root login_password="" user=root password="{{ root_password }}"
# Login with blank password and then set password``` Only problem with that is then it isn't idempotent.

Comment: You can make that action idempotent by adding a line that removes any old mysql data by basically purging mariadb or mysql prior to setting the password from blank to something.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this Ansible Module, it provides an easy and idempotent way for `mysql_secure_installation` in Ansible

---

**Example - with a fresh MySQL Installation**

```yaml
- name: test mysql_secure_installation
  mysql_secure_installation:
    login_password: ''
    new_password: password22
    user: root
    login_host: localhost
    hosts: ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1']
    change_root_password: true
    remove_anonymous_user: true
    disallow_root_login_remotely: true
    remove_test_db: true
  register: mysql_secure

# To see detailed output
- debug:
    var: mysql_secure
```

**Example - Change an existing root password**

```yaml
- name: test mysql_secure_installation
  mysql_secure_installation:
    login_password: password22
    new_password: password23
    user: root
    login_host: localhost
    hosts: ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1']
```

> **For usage**: All you have to do is create a dir called `library` in your `playbooks or role's dir` and copy the `mysql_secure_installation.py` to it,

*you can find a Full example in the following Link*

https://github.com/eslam-gomaa/mysql_secure_installation_Ansible